# c++ getopt combination of arguments

Tags: c++, command, getopt

Hi i'm playing around with geopt and i'm intressted in some input. I wanna make a simple application that can take some combination of input but not others

Let's say i type myproject -a 10 -b 5 this should be ok
but if i type myproject -a 10 without -b 5 this would not be ok.

Likewise if i were to type myproject -k -a 10 this would not be ok the only allowed combinatio is a and b.

Is this easiest accolisphed by setting flags so in each case i just set bFlag and aFlag and so on? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Boolean flags that are checked after argument parsing is really the only way to go.

Comment: i was afraid of these feels like i would need an vector of bools let's say i have 6 possible arguments and i make it so if the user calls myproject -k only k will run no matter what else is typed. then i would have to loop through the vector checking each bool :o

Comment: @mrmagin "then i would have to loop through the vector checking each bool" - why is that so terrible?

Comment: Feels like an ugly solution but maybe that's just me

Comment: If you are a programmer, you often have to translate business rules into code. Your problem is nothing else. You define first the rules what is allowed and what not, then you implement the checks. SO is not a codeing service. First make a try yourself and come back if you ran into problems. To have your code (or design) reviewed better go to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)